# Make remakes pattern rule's target even though it's newer than prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use a "fake" pattern rule in my `Makefile` to compile all of my Erlang source files with a single invocation of the compiler. It works, but for some reason make decides to always remake the target, even though it's newer than its prerequisites. What's going on here?

This is the relevant section of my `Makefile`:

```
.SUFFIXES: .erl .beam .yrl .d .app .app.src
.PHONY: all build tests clean docs distclean realclean

build: $(ERL_OBJECTS)

$(ERL_NON_PRE_OBJECTS:.beam=.bea%): $(ERL_NON_PRE_SOURCES)
    $(ERLC) -pa $(EBIN_DIR) $(ERLC_FLAGS) -o $(EBIN_DIR) $(filter $(SRC_DIR)/%.erl,$?)
```

This is the relevant part of the `make -d -p build` output:

```
Considering target file 'build'.
 File 'build' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'm'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/field_usage.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/bo_lib.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/bo.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/flags.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/bos_utilities.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/generate_bo_template.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/bo_mappings.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/document_bos.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/types.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/document_config_bos.erl'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/bo_transform.erl'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
    [...]
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/field_usage.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/bo_lib.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/bo.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/flags.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/bos_utilities.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/generate_bo_template.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/bo_mappings.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/document_bos.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/types.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/document_config_bos.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/bo_transform.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'src/field_usage.erl' is older than target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
   Prerequisite 'ebin' is order-only for target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.
  Must remake target 'ebin/field_usage.beam'.

[...]

ERL_OBJECTS := ebin/field_usage.beam ebin/bo_lib.beam ebin/bo.beam ebin/flags.beam ebin/bos_utilities.beam ebin/generate_bo_template.beam ebin/bo_mappings.beam ebin/document_bos.beam ebin/types.beam ebin/document_config_bos.beam ebin/bo_transform.beam

ERL_NON_PRE_OBJECTS := ebin/field_usage.beam ebin/bo_lib.beam ebin/bo.beam ebin/flags.beam ebin/bos_utilities.beam ebin/generate_bo_template.beam ebin/bo_mappings.beam ebin/document_bos.beam ebin/types.beam ebin/document_config_bos.beam ebin/bo_transform.beam

ERL_NON_PRE_SOURCES := src/field_usage.erl src/bo_lib.erl src/bo.erl src/flags.erl src/bos_utilities.erl src/generate_bo_template.erl src/bo_mappings.erl src/document_bos.erl src/types.erl src/document_config_bos.erl src/bo_transform.erl

ebin/field_usage.beam: src/field_usage.erl src/bo_lib.erl src/bo.erl src/flags.erl src/bos_utilities.erl src/generate_bo_template.erl src/bo_mappings.erl src/document_bos.erl src/types.erl src/document_config_bos.erl src/bo_transform.erl src/field_usage.erl | ebin
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'm'
#  Also makes: ebin/bo_transform.beam ebin/document_config_bos.beam ebin/types.beam ebin/document_bos.beam ebin/bo_mappings.beam ebin/generate_bo_template.beam ebin/bos_utilities.beam ebin/flags.beam ebin/bo.beam ebin/bo_lib.beam
#  Last modified 2019-04-10 13:04:00.763145368
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := ebin/field_usage.beam
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := m
# automatic
# + := src/field_usage.erl src/bo_lib.erl src/bo.erl src/flags.erl src/bos_utilities.erl src/generate_bo_template.erl src/bo_mappings.erl src/document_bos.erl src/types.erl src/document_config_bos.erl src/bo_transform.erl src/field_usage.erl
# automatic
# | := ebin
# automatic
# < := src/field_usage.erl
# automatic
# ^ := src/field_usage.erl src/bo_lib.erl src/bo.erl src/flags.erl src/bos_utilities.erl src/generate_bo_template.erl src/bo_mappings.erl src/document_bos.erl src/types.erl src/document_config_bos.erl src/bo_transform.erl
# automatic
# ? :=
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=2/31=6%
#  recipe to execute (from '/mybuildpath/make/stdapp.mk', line 408):
    $(PROGRESS)
    $(ERLC) -pa $(EBIN_DIR) $(ERLC_FLAGS) -o $(EBIN_DIR) $(filter $(SRC_DIR)/%.erl,$?)
```

It just doesn't make any sense to me. Why to rebuild `ebin/field_usage.beam` when it's newer than all of its dependencies? Even `$?` is set to empty by `make`.

I believe this is somehow caused by a situation when each compiled `.beam` module is newer than its corresponding `.erl` source, but there are `.erl` sources that are newer than some other `.beams`. At least adding a `touch $(ERL_NON_PRE_OBJECTS)` to the recipe solved the problem.

However, I can't reproduce the empty `$?` situation with a simplified example:

```
FILES := a b c
INS := $(FILES:%=in/%.txt)
OUTS := $(FILES:%=out/%.txt)

.PHONY: build
build: $(OUTS)

$(OUTS): | out

out:
    mkdir -p $@

$(OUTS:.txt=.tx%): $(INS)
    echo building $@ from $?
    cp -t out $?
```

For example `make; touch in/b.txt; make` would print `building out/a.txt from in/b.txt`. This points to the problem with my recipe, but I haven't managed to get an empty `$?`, no matter how the timestamps look.

Comment: Not sure it is the cause of what you see but do you know that pattern rules with several targets (your case) are treated in a very special way by make (see [the end of this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro))? Make considers that all targets are produced by one single execution of the recipe. Could it be that `ebin/field_usage.beam` gets rebuilt because another target is out-of-date? It could be that the debug output is misleading because it picks the first target instead of the one that really needs to be rebuilt...

Comment: I know about this behaviour, and this is the very reason I'm using a pattern rule with multiple targets: I want to compile all sources with a single invocation of the compiler (as it has a significant overhead of starting up).
I think some other `.beam` file being older than the newest `.erl` file is relevant, however with my simplified `Makefile` I cannot reproduce this strange behaviour, when `$?` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with my above multi-target pattern rules. One of them (in hindsight) should be obvious, the second one... not so much. I will explain these problems on my simplified example about the `in/*.txt` and `out/*.txt` files.

**1) *Every* target of a multi-target pattern rule depends on *every* prerequisite**

In other words: every target must be newer than the newest of the prerequisites. I may know that `out/a.txt` is built from `in/a.txt` and `out/b.txt` is built from `in/b.txt` respectively, but the rule tells something different to `make`. It tells that if e.g. `in/a.txt` is updated, it has to rebuild all three files in `out/`, because they all depend on `in/a.txt`. So if the recipe only updates `out/a.txt`, the next time you run `make` it will attempt to rebuild the rest of the files again:

```
$ touch in/a.txt
$ make
building out/a.txt from in/a.txt
$ make
building out/b.txt from in/a.txt
```

Please note that `$@` is always set to the first target of the multi-target pattern rule that is not newer than every prerequisite. Even though there are multiple such targets, `make` could have picked `out/c.txt` for `$@` just as well. I don't know why or how does `make` pick the target it picks for `$@`.

**Solution:** always `touch -c` every target at the end of the recipe (`-c` makes sure you won't create new files this way; in case there's a bug in your recipe and you don't build one of the targets you should it's probably better to finish with no target file than to have a bogus, empty target file on disk).

```
$(OUTS:.txt=.tx%): $(INS)
    echo building $@ from $?
    cp -t out $?
    @touch -c $(OUTS)
```

**2) Additional dependencies (such as includes) may cause `$?` to be empty**

Let's consider the case when the input files can include some header files! These inclusions introduce additional dependencies, like this:

```
out/b.txt: in/header
```

Now we can reproduce the empty `$?` scenario:

```
$ touch in/header
$ make
building out/a.txt from
cp: missing file operand
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
make: *** [Makefile:15: out/a.txt] Error 1
```

What happened?

- `out/b.txt` has to be rebuilt because it's older than `in/header`, a dependency of it.
- The multi-target pattern rule offers a recipe to rebuilt `out/b.txt` (along with `out/a.txt` and `out/c.txt`).
- For some reason, `make` picks `out/a.txt` for `$@`. I don't know why not `out/b.txt`, but it's true the `out/a.txt` is older than `in/header` too.
- Now `make` has to set `$?` and for whatever reason it doesn't set it to `in/header`. Probably because `out/a.txt` doesn't depend on `in/header`, although I still find this reasoning strange, because `in/header` is the sole reason `make` wants to use this rule.
- My demo recipe just crashed when `$?` was left empty. My original recipe, calling `erlc $?` didn't crash at least, because `erlc` is fine with being called without any actual files to recompile. But it for didn't recompile any of the modules either, which is a problem because the `touch -c` introduced before would hide this error. Basically, this way of using multi-target pattern rules **breaks incremental builds** if there are additional dependencies in the project, such as header files.

Please note that `$?` is not necessarily empty: if `$@` is set to the file with a direct dependency on the modified header, it will be set as I expected from the beginning:

```
$ touch in/header out/a.txt
$ make
building out/b.txt from in/header
```

**Solution:** there is no easy fix for this problem. My best solution so far is to introduce some marker files that are quick to generate and map directly to input files.

```
FILES := a b c
INS := $(FILES:%=in/%.txt)
OUTS := $(FILES:%=out/%.txt)
MARKS := $(FILES:%=tmp/%.mark)

mark2input = $(1:tmp/%.mark=in/%.txt)

.PHONY: build
build: $(OUTS)

$(OUTS): | out

out tmp:
    mkdir -p $@

# Regular pattern rule to create a marker file
# (with a very quick command) when an input file
# has to be recompiled.
tmp/%.mark: in/%.txt | tmp
    @echo marking $< to recompile
    $(file >$@)

# Multi-target pattern rule declares output files
# depending on marker files. The recipe however
# compiles the input files the markers correspond to.
$(OUTS:.txt=.tx%): $(MARKS)
    @echo recompiling $(call mark2input,$?)
    cp -t out $(call mark2input,$?)
    @touch -c $(OUTS)

# Dependencies must be declared on the marker files!
tmp/b.mark: in/header
```

This is a complicated `Makefile`, but at least incremental builds work well with it:

```
$ touch in/include
$ make
marking in/b.txt to recompile
recompiling in/b.txt
```